# .hasClass doesn't work inside Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

When I run, npm run test -- -u, in the command line, the test is failing. It says that it expects true when it receives false.

The problem is that .hasClass is not finding 'classname2' inside the wrapper that has the class 'classname'.

I have a wrapper.debug() in the code which shows the markup being printed out. The code the debug() function prints out is below, as well as the Jest unit test I wrote.

Why is it not working?

```
<div className="progress-bar-component">
      <div className="range text-center">
        25 of 100
      </div>
      <Progress value="25" color="danger" striped={true} animated={true} tag="div" max={100} />
</div>
```

```
it('passes in the correct value', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find('.classname).hasClass('classname2')).toEqual(true);
});
```

The jest error message is:

expect(received).toEqual(expected)

```
Expected value to equal:
  true
Received:
  false
```

Comment: the react attribute `className` (note uppercase N) yields the HTML attribute `class`. In your code, you're query-selecting `.classname`, e.g. "elements with a class attribute that contain the string `classname`", which is probably not what you actually want to do.

Comment: the ".classname" that I have in the code above is just an EXAMPLE. I'm actually using a different name for the class.

Comment: are you able to get anything from `wrapper.find()` then further check `hasClass()`. I suspect it will probably return undefined. Just based on the code you provided, the `wrapper` is `react component`, regular jquery might behave differently.

Comment: When I take out the .hasClass('nameofclass') part of the expect statement, I get an object back in the console...


 {Symbol(enzyme.__root__): {Symbol(enzyme.__root__): [Circular], Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): <ProgressBar animated={true} color="danger" max="100" striped={true} value="25" />, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "checkPropTypes": [Function checkPropTypes], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function render], "simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": ...}

Comment: @CodeJunkie do you ever check the return type of find() from official doc?  and `toEqual(val) `, I don't think you should use a Boolean `true` for `val`,  it's expected to be some objects, otherwise it will be always compare `object` to `true`, which is obviously `false`. Instead, you can check the length of the result if it's larger than zero.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the expect statement to be this...

```expect(wrapper.hasClass('progress-bar-component')).toEqual(true);```

This works. It's able to confirm that the rendered component has a class of "progress-bar-component", but it can't drill down deeper than the first node.

In other words, if I have a div container inside the top div tag and it has a class of "foo", I can't find it because it won't look past the first div tag.